# Printing with colour codes

Tags: bash, colors

I want to write some text in colour from a bash script, but the string `" -s, --with-sequence"` is not getting printed.

```
local rc="\e[0m"
local bfcode="\033[0;49;33m"
local frmt="${bfcode} %s ${rc}\n"
local _PC="printf $frmt"

$_PC " -s, --with-sequence"
```

Comment: You can't use a variable to run a command. Please don't take this the wrong way - but you have been asking a bunch of related scripting questions lately. Don't you think it would be a good idea to get some basic understanding by following a video tutorial before you progress any further?

Comment: It seems to be possible.

Comment: But it's a really, really, really bad way to write code. Did you understand my previous comment at all?

Comment: My intention was to make a shortened version of a `printf` with a format string.  I have not seen this thing discussed in tutorials.

Comment: If you want to make a customized version of a command (like `printf`), the most obvious way is to make a function doing whatever you want to do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *reliably* store a command + its arguments in a scalar (string) variable. In particular, if the arguments may contain whitespace or other shell-special characters then:

- if you **don't** double-quote the variable expansion (as you have done) then the arguments get mangled by word splitting and filename generation (aka "split + glob")
- if you **do** double-quote the expansion, then the shell can't split the string into its command + arguments.

*(In your case, `printf $frmt` is being split into 4 tokens: `printf '\033[0;49;33m' %s '\e[0m\n'` instead of the desired 2 tokens of the `printf` command and a single format string. So long as you didn't have the shell's `nullglob` option set, it would have worked if you'd omitted the spaces around the `%s` format specifier - but it's bad practice.)*

You can however reliably do it using an array:

```
$ declare -f -p pc
pc ()
{
    local rc="\e[0m";
    local bfcode="\033[0;49;33m";
    local frmt="${bfcode} %s ${rc}\n";
    local _PC=(printf "$frmt");
    "${_PC[@]}" " -s, --with-sequence"
}
```

See [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: You are correct.  Figured out that the problem occurred because of the space around the %s format specifier.

Comment: The link has been very helpful.

Comment: And your reliable way to do it is fantastic.

Comment: Are the double quotes in `"${_PC[@]}"` really necessary?

Comment: @Hovlar yes they are - the double quotes are necessary to stop each element of the expanded array from being subject to split + glob. See the `Arrays` subsection under `PARAMETERS` in `man bash`.